# The most logical way to order up-votes and down-votes and how to do it

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

In my database I have a number of up-votes and a number of down-votes for each row in the table and they represent some kind of calification for that item.

When displaying all items in a table, what would be the most logical way to order those according to the values of the votes? I have thought of:

- Number of positive votes (descendent, obviously)
- Number of positive votes - number of negative votes
- Relation between number of positive votes and negative votes

Which would make more sense?

Also, for the last one, how could I make the SQL query? How do I treat the division by 0 case here? If I chose this option, depending on the way I'm going to treat the 0 (I don't know how to do that in the order by clause), if it were the one closest to the reality (the result would be infinity), then an item with 2 up-votes and 0 down-votes would be displayed with highest priority that an item with 1000 up-votes and 3 down-votes. Doesn't this seem "unfair" for this last item?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your second option seems to be most logical to me.

Comment: FWIW, "subtraction" is a relation between those numbers. And it seems the most logical one.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. You can do something like your second one there, which is just effectively the highest rated items of all time. Another way to do it could be to do the same thing, but mix in an element of time, which could be current 'hot' items. It all depends what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Choose the method that most closely matches your specification.  If nothing is specified, ask the person for whom you are doing this.

Comment: I guess the second want makes more sense. Actually even more in the case of my list of items because once an item reaches a certain amout of votes then it has to do a "test" (check its calification) and if it "passes" the test the row is deleted from the table and moved to another one. So the items should always be displayed that way, so the ones to be about to pass would be the first ones.

Comment: @DanBracuk I am making it for myselft, I just wanted to ask what would make more sense to you guys.

Comment: Then your second option makes the most sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

It highly depends on your application but I found that up-voting is easier than down-voting... in general. So maybe you should take into consideration adding greater weight to the down votes. Going to the point maybe consider using third attribute kind of `voting_counts_coefficient` and use it without putting logic to the query. Referential integrity you can achieve by using some triggers or procedures.